# Calculation of divergences of Feynman diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, feynman-diagrams

In Peskin Schroeder, while considering gluon diagrams for $\beta$-function in QCD, they say that we can calculate the divergent part of loop diagram taking limit of zero external momenta - e.g. for diagram below we can take limit $k, k', q \to 0$.

[image]

I wonder why we can do this here and why we can't do this trick, for example, for this diagram:

[image]

Comment: The divergent part of a diagram is momentum independent. In the MS bar subtraction scheme the counterterms only subtract off these purely divergent pieces. Thus, in this scheme we don't need to care about what the external momenta are. Since this is the case, Might as well set them to any value that is convenient - in this case zero.